# SSH account locking reveals real users

Tags: ssh, pam, access-control

On my ssh server, I'm trying to hide the existence of all the users except for one. For any user besides that one user, I will get a `Password:` prompt which will never allow the user to enter. That's good. But for real users, after a certain number of attempts it will start printing "Account locked due to XX failed logins". It will not do this for the non-existant users. How can I disable this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message "Account locked due to XX failed logins" is the result of your using `pam_tally` (most probably `pam_tally2`). Just comment the corresponding lines in your PAM configuration files.

Comment: What are the corresponding lines? I can post `/etc/pam.d/sshd` if that'd help.

Comment: @thesecretmaster `grep -F -r tally /etc/pam*`

Comment: I see a relevant looking line in `system-login`, but why would that affect SSH?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. `system-remote-login` refers to `system-login`.